# codename one app version number programmatically

Tags: codenameone

I'm trying to get application version from the code at runtime

how to get `codename1.version` from `codenameone_settings.properties` programmatically

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `Display.getInstance().getProperty("AppVersion", "1.0")`, it will return the app version