# How to get app version (Play / iTunes) stores using Codename one

Tags: google-play, app-store, codenameone

How do I get published apps version number from Google Play store and Apple App Store with App ID?

Is there any Rest API to provide apps version on stores?.

Comment: Similar question answered  here http://stackoverflow.com/a/40102681/2931146.

Comment: Did you understand my question??. We looking to get Stores version number but you provide the code to get local app version. Your answer not match anywhere else. Do you have any solution for this or not?.

Comment: What's your use case?

Comment: You didn't understand my summary of the question???. Please read my question so you can understand my case

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the store version but your own version, the version number you put in before submitting the app to stores.

Use `Display.getInstance().getProperty("AppVersion", "1.0")`

To change your version number, right-click the app and select `properties` then change the Version number as necessary. The version you put in will be returned whenever you call the above line.

Comment: Did you understand my question??. We looking to get Stores version number but you provide the code to get local app version. Your answer not match anywhere else. Do you have any solution for this or not?.