# Codename One - App version format for iOS app

Tags: ios, codenameone

Reading [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40101244/codename-one-app-version-number-programmatically), I know how to programmatically get the app version, as written in codename1.version parameter.

Usually, for the version number I use the multiple-points notation *number.number.number* (e.g.: 1.0.1). But when I put the version in that notation, the *Send iOS Debug build* returns the following error:

> Can't assign value '1.0.1' to attribute version, reason: class
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException with message 'multiple points'

So, the codename1.version parameter is casted as number (float?). Why?

How can I set the multiple-points notation for codename1.version? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Versions in Codename One are always serial with 2 points after the primary digit.

Both iOS and Android support 3 number notation but they do so differently (as does microsoft) so it's hard to support such a numbering system consistently. Having said that if you REALLY want to go into that (which we strongly discourage) you can look at some of the [build hints](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html) that provide direct access to numbering/version of the native OS.